# Need help loading another instance of jquery-notif tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I need your help with a javascript action, I'm trying to load a tooltip after the original tooltip has gone. Here is the script I'm using  http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-notify/ I just need another tooltip to appear after the other one is gone.

Gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#container").notify({
   close: function(){
      alert("Notification Closed do your work here!");
      // code to open another nitification
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Imdad but I have no idea how to add another notification there :(